# Google Custom Search Box doesn't appear on first load in my Gatsby project, only appears when reloading or refreshing

Tags: gatsby, google-custom-search

**Goal:**

when site is loaded it should have the search box together with menu items in the navigation bar.

See the picture below:
[image]

**Problem:**

Currently on first load the google custom search box doesn't appear. However, when you reload/refresh the page, it will appear as normal and functions as normal. But this is annoying as people might not know I have the search box until they refresh or reload the page. This is what it appears like on first load.

[image]

UPDATE: I asked around and it loads fine for some people. I tested it several times at my end, in incognito mode, it loads fine sometimes, and it doesn't sometimes (needs reload/refresh). So... not everybody can reproduce this problem all the time. I am curious on why it happens like that.

**I have tried:**

According to [google's instruction](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox), I have done things like below:
In my gatsby project's nav component,

```
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
...
 <Helmet>
    <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=123:456"></script>
  </Helmet>
    <nav className="nav" >
      <div className="nav-container">
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/blog">All</Link>
        <Link to="/tags/food">Food</Link>
        <Link to="/tags/style">Style</Link>
        <Link to="/tags/living">Living</Link>
        <Link to="/tags/travel">Travel</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>  
        <div className="gcse-search"></div>
      </div> 
    </nav>
```

I did use devtool and saw there seems to be nothing loaded into the div where search box is supposed to appear. I have no idea why is that.

UPDATE:
Hi, I have since changed the "async" attribute to "defer" and tested it in private/incognito mode and here is the result:

*LinuxMint:*

Chromium : OK

Firefox: OK

*Manjaro (Linux)*

Chrome: OK

Firefox: flashes but doesn't load

*Windows:*

Firefox: still flashes and doesn't load

Edge: mostly OK but sometimes it doesn't work

*Iphone:*

Safari : needs refresh/reload twice before it appears

Chrome: OK

*Android:*

Chrome: OK

UPDATE: I've changed my search service to algolia now, so the live site isn't available for testing.

Here is a simpler version just made for testing purpose: [LIVE DEMO](https://sharp-easley-bcec9b.netlify.com/)
as you can see, the search box briefly flashes then disappear.

The Code is as below:

```
import React from "react"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

import Layout from "../components/layout"

import SEO from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <>
  <Helmet>
    <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=123:456"></script>
  </Helmet>
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" />
    <h1>Here goes the Google search:</h1>
    <div className="gcse-search"></div>
  </Layout>
  </>
)

export default IndexPage
```

**Question:**

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I debug and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading Josh's post: [The Perils of Rehydration](https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration) I think the problem I encountered was similar. So I did something like this.

I create a folder called hooks and write a ClientOnly.js there. As below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function ClientOnly({ children, ...delegated }) {
    const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      setHasMounted(true);
    }, []);
    if (!hasMounted) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div {...delegated}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default ClientOnly
```

Then I wrote another search.js in the component folder, as below:

```
import React from "react"
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"

const search = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <script
          async
          src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=123:456"
        ></script>
      </Helmet>

      <div className="gcse-search"></div>
    </div>
  )
}


export default search
```

Then I imported them whenever I need them as :

```
<ClientOnly>
   <Search />
</ClientOnly>
```

Now everything seems to work. You can test it here: [Live Demo](https://sharp-easley-bcec9b.netlify.com/)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why is this happening?

```
<script 

  async // <- This is the reason why your search box does not appear on first load

  src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=123:456"

></script>
```

Your page is rendered without waiting for the async call to finish. By the time you refresh the async call has finished and therefore the script can be rendered.

> 2. How can I debug and fix it?

For debugging you could attach a function to the `onLoad` event of the [script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) that fires a `console.log`.

One solution would be to trigger a rerender in `componentDidMount`. This [answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) might be helpful.

Comment: is it possible to use useEffect for that? Although... am not sure how I should write that.